# i.MX6SX run M4 firmware from DDR

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, cortex-m, cortex-a

I'm doing my tests on a `6SX-SABRE-SBD board`. This board mounts a i.MX6SX, an asymmetrical dual core CPU: `Cortex A9` and `Cortex M4`.

At the moment the system is starting with `U-Boot` and `linux kernel` from `SD`. This means that A9 run int DDR region. The M4 firmware has MQX 4.1.0 OS, freescale's porting.

**So far I did:**

1. Test the pingpong example, a sample code supplied by MQX that maps the M4 code in QSPI2. It works well.
2. I Changed the linker script (icf, I'm using IAR) of pingpong example
   to have the ROM region inside the DDR Region (eg. `0x84000000`).
3. At the start of U-Boot I stop and copy the remapped `.bin` file to the
   correct address (eg. `fatload mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} 0x84000000 myRemapped.bin`)
4. Used command bootaux of U-Boot to start M4 application (eg. `bootaux 0x84000000` and I tried `bootaux 0x8400400` also to skip vectors)

Those steps don't seem to work.

As a test I modify the standard pingpong exaple to modify some bytes at `0x84000000`, an address inside the `DDR region`, and it works well. This means that the M4 has rights to the `DDR region`.

Could someone help me to understand what is mandatory to know/modify to make a M4 firmware running in `DDR`?

Comment: The fact that you can read/write the DDR doesn't mean you could run from it. I'd first make sure that the M4 can run from external memory at all. It's quite common for the lower-end embedded MCU (which the Cortex-M4 is one of them) to be able to execute code only from the internal flash memory. Consult the chip's datasheet/reference manual.

Comment: I asked to the Freescale's FAE and He confirmed me that It can, but obviously he disn't write me how...

Comment: It should be specified in the reference manual of the specific MCU you are using. Also, Freescale has quite a lot of samples, maybe you can manage to find one (or ask of their support).

Comment: @ Eli Iser: the real problem is that the i.MX6SX is too new, released 02/25/2015. Only basics examples and no one that let me understand how to remap correctly the M4 app. On the MCU manuals (4700 pages) a little chapter (40 pages) is spent to talk about M4 core, where I cannot find out something useful for me. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Vybrid we had to run M4 from 0x0f000411 - as far as I remember ram for M4 was mapped to 0x0f000000. I don't remember why ending was 411 instead of 400 or 000, but it worked that way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Vybrid platform (Cortex A5 - Cortex M4) has a different memory map and use address aliases to map some memory ranges. i.MX6SX has  DDR ranges from 0x80000000 and RDC module that can defines ranges and access rules.